# When is HTML rendered in Angular2 apps

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, single-page-application, angular-components

Consider there's an Angular2+ app containing components numbered 1-10.

> Component 1,2,3 are in Home Page.
>   Component 1 is the bootstrapped component.
>   Component 9 and 10 are configured to lazy load.

**Now when is the HTML/CSS/JS of the Components Loaded?**

1. Only Components 1,2,3 are loaded at the start?
2. Are Components 4-8 loaded at the start of the app with empty data
   and data is    fetched on routing to that components via AJAX calls
   to the server?
3. Is it true that all the components with early loading are loaded
   at the start of the app?
4. If all early load components are loaded at start, can we see through the HTML 
   of those components or can we inspect those components in browser console?
   If not where or how is the component data stored in the client-side/ browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only Components 1,2,3 are loaded at the start?

If those 3 components are the only three of which the homepage does consist, then yes these are the only components which are built on the start.

> Are Components 4-8 loaded at the start of the app with empty data and
>   data is fetched on routing to that components via AJAX calls to
>   server?

This depends on how it's implemented. You could get all of the data from the server but you could also store it in the component itself (if you want static data). However the JS to built the components are shipped to the client, the components just aren't built. Only with lazy loading you don't ship the JS to the client (then you load it via ajax).

> Is it true that all the components with early loading are loaded on
>   start of the app?

Yes, they all are created at the start

> If all early load components are loaded at start, can we see thorough
>   the HTML of those components or can we inspect those components in
>   browser console? If not where or how is the component data stored in
>   client-side/ browser

We can't see the HTML of the components which aren't built. When you navigate accross your app (using angular build in navigation), components will built up and break down dynamically based on which components need to be rendered. You can only view a component when this is build/rendered. A component which doesn't need to be rendered will not even be present in the DOM (so you cannot see it with Devtools).